# Rename selfdefined function

Tags: zsh

Having a precmd() that does quite a lot, like checking for VCS information, I want to disable it when I'm navigating on slow mounted network drives.

I came up with the following with which I can say `slow` before changing to a slow drive and `fast` to change it back, I'm wondering if there is something easier?

```
precmd_slow() {
    not_much
}
precmd_fast() {
    precmd_slow
    somemore1
    somemore2
}

precmd() {
    precmd_fast
}

slow() {
    precmd() {
        precmd_slow
    }
}

fast() {
    precmd() {
        precmd_fast
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution but I would use just a simple conditional inside the `precmd` function checking if the current directory is mounted or not. Now doing that depends on what kind of mount it is. If the directories are known, something like this should work.

```
slowdirs="/home/joe/slowdir1:/home/joe/slowdir2:/mnt/slowdir3"
precmd() {
  isslow=0
  echo $slowdirs | tr \: \\n |
    while read line; do
      if [[ $PWD == $line* ]]; then
        isslow=1
        break
      fi
    done
  if [[ $isslow == 0 ]] ; then
     # do slow stuff

  fi
  # do non slow stuff

}
```

What this does is test if the current directory starts with (is inside), or is, one of the directories listed in the `slowdirs` variable. If it isn't one of the "slow" directories, runs the "slow commands", otherwise it skips them.

Answer (score 0):

I liked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917214/rename-selfdefined-function#14924078) given by chepner on StackOverflow, which I shall quote directly:

> In addition to the precmd function, there is also an array called
>   precmd that contains a list of functions to call at the same time. You
>   can manipulate it yourself, but zshcontrib has a function add-zsh-hook
>   to simplify matters.

Code:

```bsh
# precmd_slow and precmd_fast defined as before

autoload add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd precmd_fast

fast () {
    add-zsh-hook -d precmd precmd_slow
    add-zsh-hook precmd precmd_fast
}

slow () {
    add-zsh-hook -d precmd precmd_fast
    add-zsh-hook precmd precmd_slow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whence -f` to type out a function, replace its name, and eval the resulting function definition:

```
rename_func() {
    if (( $# != 2 )); then
        echo "Usage: rename_func <oldname> <newname>" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    oldname=$1
    newname=$2
    local code=$(echo "$newname () {"; whence -f $oldname | tail -n +2)
    unset -f $oldname
    eval "$code"
}
```

Replacing the first line will work since `whence` always applies predictable formatting to the function:

```
$ test() { true }
$ whence -f test
test () {
        true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zsh functions can be copied with `functions -c` and deleted with `unfunction`, so to rename:

```
functions -c oldfn newfn
unfunction oldfn
```